# Is there a workaround for *args in lists or for-loops in python?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I have a list with occasional sub-lists which I iterate over in a for loop.

```py
dogs = ['albert', ['betty', 'deceased'], 'charlie', ['dagmar', 'not yet born'], 'emil']
```

And I have a function, which normally processes only one value at a time and has a default value for another, which is replaced with the second list entry, if there is one.

```py
def process_list():
    for dog in dogs:
        if len(dog) == 2:
            name, status = dog
            return name, status
        else:
            status = 'alive'       # default value
            return dog, status
```

So this works, but is there a more elegant/pythonic way?
Because, when I don´t know in advance which lengths the sublists have, the function wouldn´t work for me.
Something in the fashion of *args, like this:

```py
for dog, *args in dogs:
    do_something(do, *args)
```

Comment: A much better design is to have a consistent format for your data.

Comment: I agree with @tripleee. another note: your `len(dog) == 2` will fail if a dog name is 2 letters (e.g. "Al"), you'll return `("A", "l")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do it like this:

```
    if isinstance(dog, list):
        name, status, *_ = dog
        return name, status
    else:
        status = 'alive'       # default value
        return dog, status
```

Unlike checking the `len`, the `isinstance` check directly checks whether the item is a list (or subclass thereof). The `*_` unpacks any superfluous arguments into a list named `_` (the standard placeholder for "I'm not using this").

But this, too, is profoundly un-Pythonic. It would be better to have a consistent type of element in your list, instead of mixing strings and lists. For this situation, [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) might be a nice option.